# Yii 2: Unable to send log via mail

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

This is my mailer component. 
As you can see, because of my test purposes, I'm using email on file

```
'mailer' => [
        'class'             => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath'          => '@common/mail',
        'useFileTransport'  => true,
    ],
```

This is my log component.

```
'log'       => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets'   => [
            [
                // for this target, see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html
                'class'         => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                'levels'        => ['error'],
                'categories'    => ['yii\db\*', 'email_test'],
                'message'       => [
                   'from'           => ESHOP_EMAIL,
                   'to'             => DEVELOPER_EMAIL,
                   'subject'        => 'Errore db [' . YII_ENV . ']',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

In siteControlle->actionIndex() I'm testing log and email component in this way

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    Yii::error("testing mail log", "email_test");

    Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom([ESHOP_EMAIL => ESHOP])
        ->setTo( DEVELOPER_EMAIL)
        ->setSubject("actionIndex executed on time " . date ("H:i:s"))
        ->setTextBody("Useless body")
        ->send();

    return $this->render('index');
}
```

As i expect, at every reload of the index page I got 2 `.eml` files created inside `frontend/runtime/mail` folder.

So SwiftMailer is working, and even the log system.

**Now the problem**

I try to remove use of file from `mailer` component, commenting the row

```
        'useFileTransport'  => true,
```

When I reload the index page, I got the SECOND MAIL, the one manually composed and sent, but I DO NOT RECEIVE the first mail, the one that should be automatically composed and sent by log system using SwiftMailer.

What's wrong?

Comment: Please show the mailer configuration. I don't see the trasnsport

Comment: @scaisEdge: the default transport is to use mail() php function, that's my goal

Comment: @JurgisGregov: why manual email is sent, but log email not? This cannot be due to spooling; the log email never arrives, the manual email sent arrives immediately

Comment: What if the manual email si routed via @common/mail/layout/html.php for a proper rendering and the log email not?

Comment: When tried to send email to file, rendering was perfect, so this is not the problem

Comment: @realtebo: what are contents of EmailTarget::$message during EmailTarget::composeMessage ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to everyone.

The problem was a mistake in the destination address. Using the logger the error caused email cannot be sent, but using the manual sending the destination address error is simply ignored and the email is sent.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default value for  'useFileTransport'  is `true`. Is better set to `false` and don't comment it

Comment: `'false'`  or `false`  without `' ` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a php function for sending eMail you need a transport like this

```
 'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        //'useFileTransport' => true,
        'useFileTransport' => false, //set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
        //comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'your_mail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'your_password',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
```

And if you don't use gmail you need the configure the parameter in a proper way.

Comment: You're not reading well my question. The same mailer component is sending the 'manual' composed mail but not the log. Also: the default for 'useFileTransport' is false. And: the default transport for SwiftMailer is to use php mail() function.